# How to count the items in a generator consumed by other code

Tags: python, count, generator

I'm creating a generator that gets consumed by another function, but I'd still like to know how many items were generated:

```
lines = (line.rstrip('\n') for line in sys.stdin)
process(lines)
print("Processed {} lines.".format( ? ))
```

The best I can come up with is to wrap the generator with a class that keeps a count, or maybe turn it inside out and send() things in.  Is there an elegant and efficient way to see how many items a generator produced when you're not the one consuming it in Python 2?

**Edit:** Here's what I ended up with:

```
class Count(Iterable):
    """Wrap an iterable (typically a generator) and provide a ``count``
    field counting the number of items.

    Accessing the ``count`` field before iteration is finished will
    invalidate the count.
    """
    def __init__(self, iterable):
        self._iterable = iterable
        self._counter = itertools.count()

    def __iter__(self):
        return itertools.imap(operator.itemgetter(0), itertools.izip(self._iterable, self._counter))

    @property
    def count(self):
        self._counter = itertools.repeat(self._counter.next())
        return self._counter.next()
```

Comment: When you say you create the generator, do you mean you define a function using `yield` or you create a generator object from a comprehension or similar?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is another way using [`itertools.count()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) example:

```
import itertools

def generator():
    for i in range(10):
       yield i

def process(l):
    for i in l:
        if i == 5:
            break

def counter_value(counter):
    import re
    return int(re.search('\d+', repr(counter)).group(0))

counter = itertools.count()
process(i for i, v in itertools.izip(generator(), counter))

print "Element consumed by process is : %d " % counter_value(counter)
# output: Element consumed by process is : 6
```

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: You advance the counter just for reading it, so if you do that twice it's wrong. Also `itertools.izip(generator(), counter)` is just (flipped) `enumerate`

Comment: You should delete the `- 1` when reading out the counter.  Your example should actually print `6`, since `process()` consumes the elements `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5`.

Comment: @Jochen Ritzel: sorry but i don't understand your comment about `doing it twice`?, and i don't see how `enumerate()` can get the same result because the idea is to read the counter result after, sorry but i don't see how you will do it (clean) using `enumerate()` but i agree if you say that `zip()` is the same as `itertools.izip()` in this case.

Comment: @Jochen Ritzel: I added another way to get the counter value without advancing it i didn't like it as well in the first place and i don't know if this solve the problem that you saw :).

Comment: That's what I was looking for (well, before your repr() hack, anyway. ;).  For even more gratuitous itertools goodness, you can do `itertools.imap(operator.itemgetter(0), itertools.izip(iterable, counter))`.

Comment: @Jay: It's not that evil to use the `repr()` to get the counter value , i find it more spicy :) but good.

Answer (score 16):

If you don't care that you are consuming the generator, you can just do:

```
sum(1 for x in gen)
```

Answer (score 8):

Usually, I'd just turn the generator into a list and take its length.  If you have reasons to assume that this will consume too much memory, your best bet indeed seems to be the wrapper class you suggested yourself.  It's not too bad, though:

```
class CountingIterator(object):
    def __init__(self, it):
        self.it = it
        self.count = 0
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def next(self):
        nxt = next(self.it)
        self.count += 1
        return nxt
    __next__ = next
```

(The last line is for forward compatibility to Python 3.x.)

Answer (score 2):

Here's another approach. The use of a list for the count output is a bit ugly, but it's pretty compact:

```
def counter(seq, count_output_list):
    for x in seq:
        count_output_list[0] += 1
        yield x
```

Used like so:

```
count = [0]
process(counter(lines, count))
print count[0]
```

One could alternatively make `counter()` take a dict in which it might add a "count" key, or an object on which it could set a `count` member.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to return the count and just want to log it, you can use a finally block:

```
def generator():
    i = 0
    try:
        for x in range(10):
            i += 1
            yield x
    finally:
        print '{} iterations'.format(i)

[ n for n in generator() ]
```

Which produces:

```
10 iterations
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is another solution similar to that of @sven-marnach:

```
class IterCounter(object):
  def __init__(self, it):
    self._iter = it
    self.count = 0

  def _counterWrapper(self, it):
    for i in it:
      yield i
      self.count += 1

  def __iter__(self):
    return self._counterWrapper(self._iter)
```

I wrapped the iterator with a generator function and avoided re-defining `next`. The result is iterable (not an iterator because it lacks `next` method) but if it is enugh it is faster. In my tests this is 10% faster.

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses `side_effect` from the `more_itertools` package.

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Tuple, Iterator, Callable, Iterable
from itertools import count
from more_itertools import side_effect, peekable

T = TypeVar("T")
def counter_wrap(iterable: Iterable[T]) -> \
        Tuple[Iterator[T], Callable[[], int]]:
    """
    Returns a new iterator based on ``iterable``
    and a getter that when called returns the number of times
    the returned iterator was called up until that time
    """
    counter = peekable(count())
    def get_count() -> int:
        return counter.peek()
    return (
        side_effect(lambda e: next(counter), iterable),
        get_count
    )
```

It can be used as:

```
>>> iterator, counter = counter_wrap((1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, "plast", "last"))
>>> counter()
0
>>> counter()  # Calling this has no side effect (counter not incremented)
0
>>> next(iterator)
1
>>> next(iterator)
2
>>> next(iterator)
3
>>> counter()  # Updates when the iterator returns an element
3
>>> next(iterator)
4
>>> next(iterator)
5
>>> next(iterator)
6
>>> next(iterator)
'plast'
>>> counter()
7
>>> next(iterator)
'last'
>>> counter()
8
>>> next(iterator)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
>>> counter()
8
```